# Is the given function convex? Does the point satisfy the FONC?

Tags: optimization

minimize $2x_1^2+x_2^2-2x_1x_2-4x_2$

subject to $x_1x_2\leq 4$

1. Is the objective function convex?
2. Does the point $(1,4)$ satisfy the FONC for a local minimizer?
3. Do optimal solutions of this given problem change if the constraint is replaced by the new constraint $x_1x_2\geq 4$?

I have done the following:

This is a quadratic function, rewriting it gives the Hessian to be

---

1. $\begin{bmatrix} 4&-2\\-2&2 \end{bmatrix}$ which has eigenvalues 5.2 and 0.76 so the function is convex.

---

2. The Lagrangian can be written as

$L(x,\mu)=2x_1^2+x_2^2-2x_1x_2-4x_2 -\mu(x_1x_2 -4)$

The KKT conditions are therefore:

$\nabla x L(x,\mu)=[4x_1-2x_2-\mu x_2=0,2x_2-2x_1-4-\mu x_1=0]$

$\mu(x_1x_2-4)=0$

Filling in $(1,4)$ in the first equation of $\nabla xL(x,\mu)$ gives

$4*1-2*4-4\mu =0$ so $\mu = -1$

Now using the value found for $\mu$ we fill in $(1,4)$ in the second equation of $\nabla xL(x,\mu)$. This gives

$8-2-4-(-1)1= 3 \neq 0$

Thus the point $(1,4)$ does not satisfy the FONC for a local minimizer.

---

3. I think the answer is yes, since the constraints are then changed.

---

Can someone please tell me if the answers I've given are correct or not? If not please explain why and what the right answer should be. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

i agree with (1) and (2), but (3) is non-trivial. You are optimizing a convex function over a convex interval. If the extreme values lie on the boundary, they satisfy $x_1x_2 = 4$, so that point will satisfy both sets of constraints.